# Can I run PhpStorm editor in "diff" mode - to show live changes to text like it shows in gutter

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, editor

[image]

Can I see in PhpStorm editor constantly highlighted changes made to file? Same way it is shown when you use "show diff" option in git submenu, but in default view.

Comment: Please illustrate what exactly you are after with a screenshot or two, highlighting the functionality you want to see. Just in case: modified lines are marked in the editor gutter when using VCS -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-changes-information.html#local_changes

Comment: I have added screenshot, im already using marking in gutter, i would like to have live highlight of code as well (exactly or similar to right side of diff view)

Comment: I do not think it's possible TBH / never thought of having it like this. The editor already uses different styling to highlight errors/warnings and alike, line coverages in tests etc. IMO: having diff-like view is not needed when editing the code (it distracts a lot -- need to focus on the code / to avoid mistakes there and not "what have I changed just now" -- gutter marks is enough at that stage). But obviously, every one has different needs / requirements.

Comment: What I may suggest here right now: check the Issue Track for existing tickets (maybe somebody have already asked for this -- my very quick look did not brought relevant ticket). If none found -- file a new Feature Request ticket for that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA (it's a platform-wide feature, hence the IDEA project). **That's of course, if you get no replies from other users here in a day or two.**